# How to get some part of string in linux

Tags: shell-script

The output of find command is like

> /home/user/test/folder1/abc.png

Now i want to get

> folder1

from above string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for that part of the path based on a fixed location from the left of the path or fixed depth from the right? If you are looking from the left you can do this easily with cut by using '/' as a field separator and grabbing the fourth field like this:

```
find ... | cut -d/ -f4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
path=/home/user/test/folder1/abc.def
folder=$(basename $(dirname $path))
```

or, if you want to operate on the output of find (i.e. several paths, one per line)

```
find ... | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'
find ... | sed 's#.*/\([^/]*\)/[^/]*$#\1#'
```

Comment: Don't forget quotes around a variable expansion, so: `$(basename "$(dirname \"$path\")")`

Comment: @alex, you don't need to escape the inner quotes -- they are protected by the parentheses (it's like a new "scope" for quotes). Fully quoted: `folder="$(basename "$(dirname "$path")")"`

Comment: Blows my mind, but that's true :)

Comment: The outermost quotes aren't necessary; variable assignment is one of the exceptions to word-splitting. You do still need to quote `$(dirname)` and `$path`, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use awk.

Something like:

```
find /home -name "abc.png" | awk -F"/" '{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want "folder1", then type "folder1" ...

---

If you want the second-to-last path component, this works in both `sh` and `bash`:

```
dir=${path%/*}
dir=${dir##*/}
```

(assuming `$path` contains the full path)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try:

```
find . -name abc.png -exec dirname {} \; |grep -o '[^/]*$'
```